# Extracting values from arrays in custom fields

Tags: arrays, nested

I'm trying to come up with a single array of all values in specific custom fields. The values themselves are also arrays. I've tried all sorts of array functions but haven't come across the right one or the right combination. Here is my code thus far:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'match_report',
    'post_status' => 'publish', 
    'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => 'report_home-scorers'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'report_away-scorers'
        )
    )
);

$reportscore = new WP_Query($args); 
$scorersResults = array();

if ( $reportscore->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $reportscore->have_posts() ) { 
        $reportscore->the_post();

$homescorers = get_post_meta($post->ID,'report_home-scorers',false);
$awayscorers = get_post_meta($post->ID,'report_away-scorers',false);            

foreach ($homescorers as $homescorer){
 array_push($scorersResults, $homescorer);
}
 foreach ($awayscorers as $awayscorer){
 array_push($scorersResults, $awayscorer);
}
?>

<?php } wp_reset_postdata(); //endif
}//endwhile

$scorerResults = remove_empty($scorersResults);

function remove_empty($array) {
return array_filter($array, '_remove_empty_internal');
}

function _remove_empty_internal($value) {
return !empty($value) || $value === 0;
}
```

Here what I get if I `print_r($scorerResults);` :

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 63
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 263
        [1] => 195
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
    )
)
```

I just want the values in the internal arrays in an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want the `$scoreResults` array to end up as `array(1,63,263,195)` you could use the `array_reduce` function like this:

```
function gatherScores($lhs, $rhs) {
  foreach ($rhs as $key => $value)
    if ($value)
      $lhs[] = $value;
  return $lhs;  
}

$scorerResults = array_reduce($scorerResults, "gatherScores", array());
```

I'm not sure what the blank values are in your third and fourth arrays and how they should be handled, so you may need to change the `if ($value)` condition to check for something different. As it stands it'll obviously also filter out zero scores.

Comment: Thats exactly what I wanted. I was actually thinking I'd have to run another function at the end to remove the empty values so this works wonderfully. I included an if statement so as not to have an invalid argument: `if(! empty($lhs) || ! empty($rhs))` Thank you!